# Data Model for analytical CRM as a service

Tags: sql, database-design, analytics, crm, data-modeling

We're developing an analytical CRM as a service and I have a question about **data model**.

A CRM user might upload a batch (about 1 million rows a week) with his clients/customers.
Also we already have 200 millions of rows in this database.

CRM users want us to provide a feature for estimating the amount of people in a segment defined by various constraints (sex, age, location, etc; ~50 mandatory filters) like in any advertisement platform (Facebook Ads, Google Adwords). Of course, he expects to see count result in real time.

For simplicity let's imagine you want to get a count of male smokers age 18 and 22, so you apply filters successively:

1. sex (select count (id) where sex = m)
2. age (select count (id) where sex = m and age in (18,22))
3. smokers (select count (id) where sex = m and age in (18,22) and smoker = 1)

Afterwards you might extract a list of emails from these segments (not real time).

The other thing is the operational database which only put data (operational writes from HTTPs API).

**Q.** How to make a **data model** for this case:

Which

1. type of DB and how many nodes
2. table sets, normalization and relations

to choose?

Thanks in advance!